# Contact visible to user - how?

Tags: security, sharing, contact

Our sharing setup is such that Accounts are private OWD and sharing rules are in place for role hierarchy based sharings and no other sharing criteria

Contacts are marked as "Controlled By Parent" - why can one of my users see a contact that is associated with an Account to which he doesn't have access to?  (confirmed there is a Insufficient Permissions when he tries to access the account)

Comment: If you add the `Sharing` button to the `Contact` layout you can see the exact reason.

Comment: Even with it added to the page layout, no Sharing button is rendered, presumably due to the "Controlled By Parent" setting

Comment: Hmm...not sure then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it - a rogue Permission Set that granted View All on Contact.

I had to change OWD on Contact to "Private" instead of "Controlled by Parent" in order to see the Sharing button, which then let me troubleshoot the "Why?", which told me "Adminstrator".  From this, I deduced a rogue View All.  Thanks to @ittookten on Twitter for helping with suggestions.